# Add Button to Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I'm pushing from a `ViewController` without a navigation controller to a `ViewController` with one.

I programmatically am creating the `NavigationController`, however, I'm having difficulty adding a button to the navigation bar.

```
func goToLocation() {
    let locationTableVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "locationProfile") as! LocationTableViewController
    locationTableVC.documentId = selectedDocumentId!

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: locationTableVC)

    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

LocationTableViewController.swift

```
// MARK: - View Will Appear
override public func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    // Make Nav Bar Translucent and Set title font/color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back-arrow-white")

}
```

Comment: What button do you want to add?

Comment: a custom back button

Comment: `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(.....)` or `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(....)` Note: Doesn't have to be done in `viewWillAppear`.. it can be done in `viewDidLoad`. Only accessing `navigationBar` property requires `viewWillAppear` or the constructor. If you want ALL back buttons to be a custom image instead, use `UIAppearance` proxy.

Comment: @Brandon then I override the back button set coming from another view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UIBarButtonItem using custom view & set it to leftBarButtonItem of navigationItem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    backButton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: 45, height:45)
    backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "back-arrow-white"), for: .normal)
    let backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: backButton)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;

 }
```